# MVC WebGrid with dynamic link text

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a WebGrid that looks like the following -

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(
                format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("MyOrderNumber", "Index", new { ordernumber = item.OrderNumber }).ToString()
            )
        )
    ))
```

This creates links in the grid with the link text of "MyOrderNumber".

Instead of the link text being "MyOrderNumber", I want the text to be the dynamically generated `item.OrderNumber`. But when I put `item.OrderNumber` in place of "MyOrderNumber" I get the compilation error - `The best overloaded method match for WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Funct<dynamic, object>, string, bool)`

How can I make the link text be the dynamically generated `item.OrderNumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just having to cast the dynamic variable with `(string)` like this -

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
            format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink((string)item.OrderNumber, "Index", new { ordernumber = item.OrderNumber }).ToString()
        )
    )
))
```